# Changing bullet style (e.g. color) using Google Docs API

Tags: google-docs-api

I want to change style of bullet without changing text style. I tried updateTextStyle, but it works for whole text with bullet, also I noticed, that bullet doesn't occupy an index, so I can't change it using position.

This is what I want:

[image: What I want]

Comment: I think that unfortunately, your goal cannot be directly achieved using Google Docs API, because, in the current stage, the text style of paragraph bullet cannot be managed. So, how about reporting this to the Google issue tracker as a future request? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

Comment: @Tanaike Thank's for answer, I will add later

Comment: Thank you for replying. In this case, by including my comment, how about posting it as an answer? By this, it might be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that unfortunately, goal cannot be directly achieved using Google Docs API, because, in the current stage, the text style of paragraph bullet cannot be managed.